# socket creation in C++

Tags: c++, sockets

I am novice in c++, trying a implementation of VCONFIG (VLAN) in C++.
As my main .cpp has different functions to add/rem/set priority to VLANs, I use socket to do those operations.

I would like to create socket only (once) when constructor is called, and to validate whether socket is created or not in every function.

I used the socket creation function in constructor and I checked in each function but ended with **Bad file descriptor** error.

Here is code snippet of .h file

```
 class  CVLANConf
 {
    private:
       int m_sockfd;

    public:

        CVLANConf() {
            m_sockfd = (socket (AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0));
          }
        ~CVLANConf();

  }
```

code snippet of .cpp file

```
    ABC::CVLANConf::CVLANConf()
    {

     }

     ABC::CVLANConf::~CVLANConf()
     {

     }

     void ABC::CVLANConf::VlanInitialize()
     {
      VlanAdd(Interface, 5);
     }

     void  ABC:CVLANConf::VlanAdd(UCHAR* InterfaceName, USHORT VlanID)
     {


   if (m_sockfd > 0) {
       /*FILL vlan_ioctl_args structure*/
      vlan_request.cmd     = ADD_VLAN_CMD;
          vlan_request.u.VID   = add_vid;
          strncpy(vlan_request.device1, add_iface , sizeof(add_iface) );

          /*IOCTL*/

          if (ioctl (m_sockfd, SIOCSIFVLAN, &vlan_request) < 0)
           fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: trying to add VLAN #%u to IF -:%s:- error: %s\n",VlanID, add_iface, strerror(errno));

           else
            fprintf(stdout,"Added VLAN with VID == %u to IF -:%s:-\n",add_vid, add_iface);
      }
```

I am working on Linux, now my question is whether Socket creation in constructor in .h file is correct or can I do in .cpp file. If I do it in .cpp file what is the difference ?

So anybody can please clarify me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Joe in Linux Platform

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should check the descriptor after creation in constructor.

1. If socket in constructor is good then in other functions you use differ(from initialized) socket variable. In this case it's your code problem.
2. If the descriptor is bad in constructor too you should revise the descriptor initialization code.
3. Also possible that descriptor checking code has mistake.

Anyway code snippet of your problem will be helpful.